# Angular unselect item in all selected items

Tags: angularjs

Below is my code. When user clicks on "select all" all items get selected.

what I want is when user click on any option that option should be disabled.

```js
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', []);
app.controller('sampleController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.selectAll = false;

  }
])
```

```css
.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <label ng-click="selectAll = !selectAll">Select all</label>
    <div ng-class="selectAll ? 'enable' : 'disabled'">Option 1</div>
    <div ng-class="selectAll ? 'enable' : 'disabled'">Option 2</div>
    <div ng-class="selectAll ? 'enable' : 'disabled'">Option 3</div>
    <div ng-class="selectAll ? 'enable' : 'disabled'">Option 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap each item into a new object and place a field 'selected' on this object:

```js
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', []);
app.controller('sampleController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.options = [{
      selected: false,
      item: 'option 1'
    }, {
      selected: false,
      item: 'option 2'
    }, {
      selected: false,
      item: 'option 3'
    }]

    $scope.selectAll = function(select) {
      angular.forEach($scope.options, function(o) {
        o.selected = select;
      });
    };

  }
])
```

```css
.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <label ng-click="selectAll(true)">Select all</label>
    <label ng-click="selectAll(false)">Deselect all</label>
    <div ng-repeat="option in options" ng-class="{'disabled': !option.selected}" ng-click="option.selected = !option.selected">{{option.item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However, I have given example with only 4 option. In really case I have multiple options. Is there any other way rather than adding '$scope.option'. I have wrote static html. For which every option is in different div.

Comment: if you want to apply ng-class on each individual option, you have to somehow put the options on the $scope. Otherwise, angular cannot apply the binding.

Comment: in my solution, every options is a different div as well, because I use ng-repeat. The good thing about using ng-repeat, is that you can add or remove as many options as you like, and your code will still work